# Using awk to determine Users who have UID =590 and home directory with characters shorter than 9

Tags: bash, unix, awk

As the title says How can I show the UNIX users whose UIDs is upper than 590 and their home directory is shorter than 9 characters

I used this command :

awk -F: '{if ($3 >= 590 && ($5 < 9) ) { print $3 $5 }}' /etc/passwd

But alas...... :( can someone help?

thanks

Comment: Just edited it, added a command I used.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using length($5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F: '{ if( $3 >= 590 && length($5) < 9) { print $3"\t"$5 } }' /etc/passwd
```